# Disable VLAN1 in Data Center environment - proper way to do this

Tags: data-center

please explain do I understand correctly disabling vlan 1 in DC environment
I have network switch and few bare metal servers (image below). Servers are connected to the switch by utp cable.
Now every server is connected to vlan1. But I want to disable this type of traffic and I don't know if my thnking is correct.
So I need to:

- enable i.e. vlan 2 as native
- vlan 3 as management
- all network switch ports as trunk
- every port have only allowed vlan (switchport trunk allowed vlan 4,100 )
  On router is any configuration needed ? I'm using VyOS

[image: DCArchitecture]

Comment: First, you don not use VLAN 1 because it is the default. Next, you do not use a native VLAN because that is a security risk (tag all VLANs on a trunk). Also, the VyOS manufacturer does not offer optional, paid support, so it is off-topic here.

Comment: Most switches will not allow disabling VLAN1 -- it's were a number of non-vlan aware protocols (STP) run. You can remove VLAN1 from every port, but it will still exist. (technically, those protocols run *untagged*, so they'll use whatever *native vlan* is configured., but internally it'll be 1 which can result in traffic leakage.)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yes - if you remove VLAN 1 from all trunks and untagged ports it's effectively offline.

Of course, your router needs to be configured in the same way if it uses a trunk link. Basically, if all your switches drop any frames tagged with VLID 1 then any device still trying to use it gets no connectivity on that VLAN.

Comment: does router in my DC need to know what is native vlan ?
I can't see that option in VyOS documentation

Comment: The *native VLAN* is the one that remains untagged on a VLAN trunk. Best practice is to not use a native VLAN but tag all frames. Whatever you do, both sides of a trunk need to use the exact same configuration.

Comment: ok thanks, so if I understand properly. On router side does not need to be configured some 802.1q information about other native vlan?

Comment: Not if you don't configure an untagged = native VLAN on the trunk.

Comment: ok now it is fully understood, thanks @Zac67